# python skipping for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

So my problem is that my code is skipping the last three "for" loops. here is my full code:

```
import os
import os.path
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
def RNA2ENZ(RNA, number):
    if RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UUU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UUC":
        letter = "F"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UUA" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UUG":
        letter = "L"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CUU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CUC" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CUG" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CUA":
        letter = "L"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AUU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AUC" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AUA":
        letter = "I"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AUG":
        letter = "M"
        return letter 
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GUU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GUC" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GUA" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GUG":
        letter = "V"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UCU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UCC" or RNRNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UCA" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UCG":
        letter = "S"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CCG" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CCC" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CCA" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CCU":
        letter = "P"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "ACG" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "ACA" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "ACC" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "ACU":
        letter = "T"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GCU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GCC" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GCA" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GCG":
        letter = "A"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UAU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UAC":
        letter = "Y"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UAA" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UAG":
        letter = "."
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CAU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CAC":
        letter = "H"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CAA" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CAG":
        letter = "Q"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AAU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AAC":
        letter = "N"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AAA" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AAG":
        letter = "K"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GAU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GAC":
        letter = "D"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GAA" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GAG":
        letter = "E"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UGU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UGC":
        letter = "C"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UGA":
        letter = "."
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "UGG":
        letter = "W"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CGU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CGC" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CGA" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "CGG":
        letter = "R"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GGU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GGC" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GGA" or RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "GGG":
        letter = "G"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AGU" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AGC":
        letter = "S"
        return letter
    elif RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AGA" or  RNA[0][number:number + 3] == "AGG":
        letter = "R"
        return letter
    else:
        letter = "-"
        return letter
def DNA2RNA(Strand, numb):
        if Strand[0][numb] == "G":
            letter = "G"
            return letter
        elif Strand[0][numb] == "C":
            letter = "C"
            return letter
        elif Strand[0][numb] == "T":
            letter = "U"
            return letter
        elif Strand[0][numb] == "A":
            letter = "A"
            return letter
def DNAfilp(DNA, num):
        if DNA[0][num] == "G":
            letter = "C"
            return letter
        elif DNA[0][num] == "C":
            letter = "G"
            return letter
        elif DNA[0][num] == "T":
            letter = "A"
            return letter
        elif DNA[0][num] == "A":
            letter = "T"
            return letter
clear()
print("please delete the 5' and 3' from the file")
filename = raw_input("please enter file name to convert:")
clear()
intron = raw_input("are there any introns? If so enter 'yes' else enter 'no':")
if intron == "yes":
    clear()
    intronfile = raw_input("please enter the file name with the introns and please make sure there is a space inbetween each intron (tip:max of five):")
else:
    print("")
clear()
outputfileDNA = raw_input("please enter outputfile for DNA name:")
clear()
outputfileRNA = raw_input("please enter outputfile for RNA name:")
clear()
outputfileENZ = raw_input("please enter outputfile for ENZ name:")
clear()
prime = input("which is first 5' or 3' (tip: just enter the number):")
clear()
file = open(filename, 'r')
DNA = file.read()
DNAlength = len(DNA)
DNA = DNA.split()
intfile = open(intronfile, 'r')
introns = intfile.read()
introns = introns.split()
print(introns)
num = 0
code = ""
raw_input()
clear()
for number in range(0, DNAlength):
    code = code + DNAfilp(DNA, num)
    num = num + 1
if prime == 5:
    realcode = "3'" +code + "5'"
elif prime == 3:
    realcode = "5'" + code + "3'"
else:
    realcode = code
if prime == 5:
    DNAtop = "5'" + DNA[0] + "3'"
elif prime == 3:
    DNAtop = "3'" + DNA[0] + "5'"
else:
    DNAtop = DNA[0]
outputDNAstrand = DNAtop + " " + realcode
DNAstrand = code + " " + DNA[0]
realcode = realcode.split()
code = code.split()
RNA = ""
numb = 0
if prime == 5:
    Strand = DNA
elif prime == 3:
    Strand = code
else:
    Strand = DNA
for number in range(0, DNAlength):
    RNA = RNA + DNA2RNA(Strand, numb)
    numb = numb + 1
count = 0

raw_input()
RNA = str(RNA)

for number in range(0, len(introns)):
    RNA = RNA.replace(introns[count], "")
    count = count + 1
RNA = RNA.split()
print(RNA[0])

ENZlength = len(RNA)/3
number1 = 0
number2 = 1
number3 = 2
ENZ1 = ""
ENZ2 = ""
ENZ3 = ""
raw_input()

for number in range(0, ENZlength):
    ENZ1 = ENZ1 + RNA2ENZ(RNA, number1)
    number1 = number1 + 3
    raw_input()
raw_input()
for number in range(0, ENZlength):
    ENZ2 = ENZ2 + RNA2ENZ(RNA, number2)
    number2 = number2 + 3
for number in range(0, ENZlength):
    ENZ3 = ENZ3 + RNA2ENZ(RNA, number3)
    number3 = number3 + 3


outputENZ = " ENZ1:  " + ENZ1 + " ENZ2:  " + ENZ2 + " ENZ3:  " + ENZ3
outputRNA = "RNA: " + str(RNA[0])
if os.path.isfile(outputfileDNA) == True:
    os.remove(outputfileDNA)
out_file = open(outputfileDNA, "w")
out_file.write(outputDNAstrand)
out_file.close()
if os.path.isfile(outputfileRNA) == True:
    os.remove(outputfileRNA)
out_file = open(outputfileRNA, "w")
out_file.write(outputRNA)
out_file.close()
if os.path.isfile(outputfileENZ) == True:
    os.remove(outputfileENZ)
out_file = open(outputfileENZ, "w")
out_file.write(outputENZ)
out_file.close()
raw_input("all done!")
```

this code was working all fin before I added these lines:

```
RNA = str(RNA)

for number in range(0, len(introns)):
    RNA = RNA.replace(introns[count], "")
    count = count + 1
RNA = RNA.split()
```

I do not know why this  would change anything but it did. What I am trying to do is to convert one strand of DNA to RNA then to an Enzyme code (the DNA is a cipher in which certain enzymes equal certain letters). my code creates the DNA and RNA fine but it skips the last 3 for loops for unknown  reason. Any help would be great.

[EDIT] The code finishes normally but it does not run the loop. It even bypasses the raw_input in the loops themselves. Also the

Comment: Do your programme crashes in this place or only exit in normal way?
Post please minimal example when you achieve this behaviour, please.
I've try to execute it, but it ask to many questions («please enter outputfile for …»), and I do not undestand what it wants.

Comment: What type of variable is RNA before you execute `RNA = str(RNA)`? Are you sure it's of the same type as the one you have at the end of that piece of code, so when you `split` the string (which will only split on whitespace, if you haven't given it any other parameters). Also, your code is full of optimization possibilities. In your first function, consider getting rid of all the `return letter` statements and bring those to the end of the function. It will improve the readability.

Comment: You are replacing introns[count] with "". Does this remove much of the RNA string? Can you print the length before and after you do the removal?

Comment: Your code is extremely repetitive.  You should extract `RNA[0][number:number + 3]` into a variable and then simply use `variable in ["FOO", "BAR"]` to check the sequences in each `elif`.  (I'm sure there would be better ways still to refactor this, but as a start.) http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out what my problem was when looking over @Austin Hastings question. ENZlength which is defining how long the for loop is is actually finding the wrong length. It is doing len(RNA) which is 1 because it is reading how many lists there are when the actual answer should be len(RNA[0]) which is how many characters are in the first item.